# Could not find a getter for emp_id in class

Tags: java, getter-setter

emplyeer.java

```
package sibintergartionp;

public class emplyeer {

    private int emp_id;  
    private String name;  
    private String address;
    private String desig;
    emplyeer empr=new emplyeer();
    public void setemp_id(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        emp_id=i;
    }
    public void setname(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        name=string;
    }
    public void setaddress(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        address=string;
    }
    public void setdesig(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        desig=string;
    }

}
```

---

emplyee.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"  
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">   
<hibernate-mapping>  
<class name="sibintergartionp.emplyeer" table="emp">    
           <id name="emp_id">  
          <generator class="assigned"></generator>  
          </id>
            <property name="name"></property> 
            <property name="address"></property>
            <property name="desig"></property>
</class>              
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

testclass.java

```
package sibintergartionp;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;   
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;  
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;  
public class testclass {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        Resource r=new ClassPathResource("context.xml");  
        BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(r);  
        employeedao dao=(employeedao)factory.getBean("d");  
        emplyeer e=new emplyeer();  
        e.setemp_id(114);  
        e.setname("varun");  
        e.setaddress("Vastra`enter code here`pur");  
        e.setdesig("Analyst");  
        dao.saveEmployee(e);  
    }  
}
```

---

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"  ?>
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
        <property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.driver"></property>  
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"></property>  
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>  
        <property name="password" value="root1234"></property>
        <property name="initialSize" value="1000" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="25" />  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="mysessionFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>  

        <property name="mappingResources">  
        <list>  
        <value>emplyee.hbm.xml</value>  
        </list>  
        </property>  

        <property name="hibernateProperties">  
            <props>  
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>  
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>  

            </props>  
        </property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate">  
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="d" class="sibintergartionp.employeedao">  
    <property name="template" ref="template"></property>  
    </bean>  


    </beans>
```

---

error:

> org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot load JDBC driver
>   class 'com.mysql.jdbc.driver'
>
> caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver
>
> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'd' defined in class path resource
>   [context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'template' while
>   setting bean property 'template'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'template' defined in class path resource
>   [context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mysessionFactory'
>   while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path
>   resource [context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a
>   getter for emp_id in class sibintergartionp.emplyeer

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'template' defined in class path resource [context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mysessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for emp_id in class sibintergartionp.emplyeer

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a getter for emp_id in class sibintergartionp.emplyeer

Comment: Because you don't have one?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're asking here.  The error message is very clear; it's trying to invoke a method you haven't written.  Why haven't you just gone ahead and written the getter that it's looking for?

Comment: Follow the basic Java naming conventions which is independent of Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You have got the wrong driver name here:

```js
<property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.driver"></property>
```

It should be

```js
<property name="driverClassName"  value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
```